# how to pass one data view and others view page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7

i have two pages file in my view
first is my `home blade` then second is `category blade` and both of them using `extends asidenav`
my problem is when im redirecting to **category file** it gives me a error `Undefined variable: categories` but in my **home file** when im redirecting it's working fine . i will describe my code.

in my controller `HomeController` i pass one data  **`categories`** to `home.blade.php`

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $categories = Category::select('id','name')->get();

        return view('home', compact('categories'));
     }

     public function category(){
        return view('category');
     }
}
```

the output of my `home.blade.php`

```
@extends('asidenav')
@section('section')
<main>
    this is homepage
</main>
@endsection
```

you can see in my **home blade** there is a extends  **asidenav** . inside of my asidenav extends the **data categories** i passed is inside of that asidenav to make a list of categories

the output of my **extends asidenav**
where the data i pass `categories`

```
<ul>    
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <li><a href="{{ route('category',$category->id) }}"><span>{{ $category->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

when i click the `ahref` to redirect the category blade it gives the error undefined variable categories. but when im redirecting to home blade it's working
the output of my `category.blade.php`

```
@extends('asidenav')
@section('section')
<main>
    this is category
</main>
@endsection
```

but when i tried this code in my **category** controller it's working fine the error of undefined variable categories not showing

```
   public function category()
        {
          $categories = Category::select('id','name')->get();

             return view('category', compact('categories'));
        }
```

my point here is i want to pass only single `data categories` in my home blade and others file blade like a `props` but i don't have a idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a service provider responsible for inyecting those variables without declaring them in your controller, in your boot method :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

View::composer(['asidenav', 'home'], function($view){
    $categories = Category::all();

    return $view->with('categories', $categories);
})
```

Comment: thank you for this answer i preciated.. you forgot to include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`